# How to perform multiple events CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

This has been bugging me for a while, I was wondering what is the best way to make all elements within a div act differently on hover.

Example HTML

```
<div class="box">
<a href="">
<h1>Box Title</h1>
<span class="icon floatr"></span>
</a>
</div>
```

Now I'd normally do the following css;

```
 a.span {color:black}
  a.span:hover {color:red;}
```

But is there anyway to group them together; so that on hover it will action two different selectors without using JS?

I.E: Change the icon to red and the text adds a text shadow or something.

Comment: Please [accept answers for your previous questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to encourage others to help you in the future.

Answer (score 7):

`:hover` the parent element instead:

```
.box:hover h1 {
   /* styles */
}
.box:hover span {
   /* different styles */
}
```

Comment: Will that work no matter where the hover target area is? Or will the span only change if you hover over it's exact co-ordinates?

Comment: It's triggered whenever you `hover` over the `.box` element. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use `:hover` for the **parent element**, like so:

```
a:hover h1 {
   color: blue;
}

a:hover span {
   color: red;
}
```

Not for your particular case, but you could also use the **sibling selector** to target only the next sibling, like so:

```
.element:hover + .next-sibling {
   color: red;
}
```